# jQuery animate() - get progress with easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, easing

Currently, I'm using this code to animate a bar-graph-esque element:

```
$('.anim').animate({
    right: `${100-(e/max*100)}%`,
    backgroundColor: colors[0]
},{
    duration: 1500,
    easing: 'easeInQuart',
    progress: function(animation, progress, msRemaining) {
        console.log(100 * progress + "%");
        document.getElementById('progress').innerText = Math.round(e * progress);
    }
});
```

([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z3nwy87/))

Where `e` is the value of the bar and `max` is the total bar graph scale.

The element `progress` is supposed to show the value of the bar graph as it increases.

However, since I'm using `'easeInQuart'`, the numeric progress of the bar graph isn't actually its visual state.

Here's a [slowed down example](https://jsfiddle.net/2z3nwy87/2/) where you can clearly see that the progress text counts up at a constant rate, but the animated bar fills in with easing.

> Is there a way to get the progress, factoring in the exponential growth of `'easeInQuart'`?

Also: I might change the easing style, so I'd like the solution to be adaptable.

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: Looks to already behave the way you want. Increase the duration and change the easing to "easeInOutQuart", and you can better see the behaviour.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Nope, the numeric progress grows at a constant rate, not the rate of the easing.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, but I'll write an answer for you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain an "eased" value, instead of a `progress` callback, use a `step` callback and inspect its `now` argument.

In this case, as none of the animated properties gives you the value you want, you can animate a custom property, which jQuery makes very simple.

```
var e = 3210;
var max = 4504;
var colors = ['#28ad8a'];
$('.anim').css({
  'val': 0 // custom property: start value 
}).animate({
  'right': `${100-(e/max*100)}%`,
  'val': e, // custom property: final value: 
  'backgroundColor': colors[0]
}, {
  'duration': 1500,
  'easing': 'easeInQuart',
  'step': function(now, tween, msRemaining) {
    if (tween.prop === 'val') { // this callback is called once per property per step, therefore filter out all but the property of interest, 'val'
        $('#progress').text(Math.round(now));
    }
  }
});
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z3nwy87/4/)**